# Reopening recent question

Tags: discussion

Question [How do I deal with an client with autism to stop talking to me?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/28022/6299) was closed with the comment that the question needs to have a specific goal.  It seems like the goal is pretty well elucidated.  I'm guessing that the question may have been closed because it sounded somewhat objectionable, but in that case it would be better to be clear about the reason.
So my end goal is to either have the question reopened, or an explanation here as to what could be added to it to give it a specific goal.

Answer (score 1):

It is in no way ready to be reopened yet. It lacks information by the OP on how they have handled things so far in an attempt to stop this, or why they think their regular interpersonal skills to achieve this goal won't work. Also, from the close reason:

> and how you would like to interact with the others involved.

This information is also still missing. Unless OP updates their question to add the missing information as asked for in the close reason, this shouldn't be reopened. Just replacing "How to deal with this" with "How to deal with this so that" doesn't add that information, and doesn't improve the question to a state where it should be reopened. It is still asking for what to do without giving any clue on what OP wants to do, what Interpersonal Skill they need help with.